# orientdb - How to filter child vertexes without traverse

Tags: database, orientdb, graph-databases

I haму class `State` extended from `V`, Records of `State` connected into graph with `E`. Also i have variable with rid: `$current`. How to select other outgoing `State` from `$current` and filter them with `WHERE`?

I know how to implement if with `TRAVERSE`, but is it possible to do it without it?

```
SELECT EXPAND(out()) FROM (TRAVERSE out() FROM $current MAXDEPTH 1) WHERE out().keys IN ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about this?

```
select expand(out()) from $current where out().keys IN ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

**EDIT**

here is my sample data
 [image: data]

with the previous query I obtain these results that sounds a bit incorrect to me
 [image: query1]

---

instead of that I wrote this that looks more correct:

```
select from (select expand(out()) from $current) where keys IN ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

resulting in:
 [image: query2]

---

Let me know if this helps you. Ivan

Comment: Is it normal practice to use `out().keys` in `WHERE` case?

Comment: actually I don't think it's working properly, I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I'm looking.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried with this example that is very similar to that of @Ivan Mainetti

This is my graph

[image]

With your query I get this result

[image]

The node 12:0 is the node with key "a"

With `TRAVERSE out() FROM 12:0 MAXDEPTH 1` you get state "a","b","d"

With `select FROM (TRAVERSE out() FROM 12:0 MAXDEPTH 1) WHERE out().keys IN ['a', 'b', 'c']`

You will get starting from the states 'a', 'b', 'd' , the states which are connected in output with at least one of the following states 'a', 'b' and 'c'.
You will get the state "a" that is connected to "b" and  the state "b" that is connected to "c".

With `select expand(out())FROM (TRAVERSE out() FROM 12:0 MAXDEPTH 1) WHERE out().keys IN ['a', 'b', 'c']`
you'll get the states connected in output to "a" and "b" that are b, d, c and e.

If you want to do this without using "traverse" you can use

```
select expand(out()) from (
select expand($c)
let $a=(select from 12:0),
    $b=(select expand(out()) from $a),
    $c=unionAll($a,$b)
) where out().keys IN ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good solution with let.